# Expected value in dice game

Tags: probability

Consider the following game:

Successive rolls six six-sided dice are made.

In each roll some (o none) numbers are marked.

The goal is to mark the 6 numbers.

A number can be marked only if you have marked the previous number (in the current roll or earlier).

If $X$ is the number of rolls needed to win the game, what is the exact value of $\mathbf{E}[X]$?
In the two examples below they were obtained $X = 6$ and $X = 2$ (each row corresponds to a roll and green the marked numbers).

Win in six rolls:

[image]

Win in two rolls:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start by computing the chance to get the next $n$ numbers you need.  The chance to get $0$ is $(\frac 56)^6$.  To get $1$, you need to get that one and not get the next one, so the chance is $6(\frac 16)(\frac 56)^5$.  To get $2$, the chance is ${6 \choose 2}(\frac 16)^2(\frac 56)^4$ and so on.  If you don't need that many, add in the chances of getting more.

Let $x_i$ be the expected number of rolls given that you already have $i$ numbers.  If you already have $5$, the expected number of rolls is $x_5=1+(\frac 56)^6x_5$ because if you don't get a $6$ you are back where you started.  $x_5\approx 1.5035$  If you already have $4$, we have $x_4=1+6(\frac 16)(\frac 56)^5x_5+(1-(\frac 56)^6-6(\frac 16)(\frac 56)^5)x_4$ because on the next roll you might get them both, you might get $1$ and need $x_5$ more tries, or you might get none and need $x_4$ more tries.  They get messier each step, but the approach is the same.  If you are happy with numerics, you can put it into a spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

Of the $46,656$ possible dice rolls:

- each individual number appears $31,031$ times.
- A 2-run starting at any particular number appears $19,502$ times.
- 3-runs appear $11,340$ times
- 4-runs appear $5,880$ times
- 5-runs appear $2,520$ times
- $720$ rolls contain 6-runs.

These numbers do not exclude longer runs: for instance, only $19,502 - 11,340 = 8,162$ rolls have a run that goes 2-3 but not 2-3-4.  So transitioning from state 1 to state 3 only has $8,162$ possible ways it can happen.

With this information we can determine the state transition matrix:

$$A = \frac{1}{46656}\left(\begin{matrix}
15,625 & 11,529 & 8,162 & 5,460 & 3,360 & 1,800 & 720 \\
0 & 15,625 & 11,529 & 8,162 & 5,460 & 3,360 & 2,520 \\
0 & 0 & 15,625 & 11,529 & 8,162 & 5,460 & 5,880 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 15,625 & 11,529 & 8,162 & 11,340 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 15,625 & 11,529 & 19,502 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 15,625 & 31,031 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 46,656
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Finding the number of tries a typical game will take is then a matter of applying this matrix repeatedly to the start state, $(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$; after $n$ applications, the value in the last slot will tell you the probability of the game having finished in $n$ or fewer rolls.

Unfortunately, the game is potentially infinite: there is no ironclad guarantee you'll ever see a particular number when you need it, so this appears (at first blush) to require an infinite number of additions.

---

But that's only at first blush.

The part that is potentially infinite here is simply this: that we will fail, potentially infinitely many times, to progress.  These are the $15,625$s along the diagonal: $(5/6)^6$ of the time we will not progress at all.  This is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)!  On average it will take $\frac{46,656}{31,031}$ rolls to get a success.

With this we can make progress!

So the expected number of rolls to get from having the value $n$ to completing the task is $x_n$:

$x_6 = 0$

$x_5 = \frac{46,656 + 31,031x_6}{31,031}$

$x_4 = \frac{46,656 + 19,052x_6 + 11,529x_5}{31,031}$

$x_3 = \frac{46,656 + 11,340x_6 + 8,160x_5 + 11,529x_4}{31,031}$

etc.

This gets to some big fractions pretty quickly.  I've plugged it into Excel; it gave me $2.386$.  Honestly that feels low though!

Comment: ...But the expected number of tries is certainly finite, as every mean hitting time of every finite irreducible Markov chain.

Comment: Indeed; this will converge eventually.  This doesn't make the number of attempts - and the number of things we must weigh - any less infinite though!  But: it actually turns out there is a way of doing this finitely, because we have the geometric distribution.

Comment: An upper bound to the expected number of rolls is six times my $x_5$ or about $9$.  This would be the expected number if we were only allowed to mark one number per roll, and marking more than one number can only reduce the expectation.

Comment: @DanUznanski Keyword in my comment: `expected`.

Comment: I agree.  But the expected length of a potentially infinite sequence involves, at first blush, examining the probability of each of those infinite possible sequences.

Comment: You've got the right idea, but your calculations are off. I get $x_0\approx 4.6211$.

Comment: Your equation for $x_3$ is not right. It should be $x_3=1+A_{3,3} x_3+A_{3,4}x_4+A_{3,5} x_5.$

Comment: "The part that is potentially infinite here is simply this: that we will fail, potentially infinitely many times, to progress." Well, no, and this is actually a serious mistake to think that such is the problem. Rather, we are faced with a nonnegative random variable $X$, always finite, say, and we are debating whether $E(X)$ is finite or infinite. Both situations can occur, a priori, only, for hitting times of finite Markov chains, a *theorem* states that $E(X)$ is finite (and the proof shows that $E(e^{sX})$ is finite for some positive $s$, in particular $E(X^n)$ is finite for every $n$).

Comment: Think we're talking past each other.  What I'm saying is that the typical simple tools for calculating expected value -- in this case, $E = \sum_kkp(k)$ -- appear to require an infinite sum.  That this sum converges may be obvious from the nature of the problem; but it doesn't necessarily mean we have tools sufficient to find the exact value.  In this case, we do.